# Add a timestamp for a variable in python

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have a function that does calculations over data in real time. I have some duplicates and I want to add timestamp for the first time I saw the duplicate and present the timestamp in the function. How to define the timestamp and how to find the firat time the duplicate has created?

```
def function_name(real_time_data):
    ...
    return dict([data1,data2]),time_created
```

The output shuld look like

```
{John: 1, sally: 1}, Wed Mar  2  13:00,
{John: 2, sally: 2}, Wed Mar  2  13:00, #this output counted at 13:05 and first seen at 13:00
{Jordan: 1, Tom: 1}, Wed Mar  2  13:15,
{John: 3, sally: 3}, Wed Mar  2  13:00,
{Jordan: 2, Tom: 2}, Wed Mar  2  13:15
```

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example of `real_time_data`?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking how to create a timestamp? Do you want the timestamp for the current time? Or for a set time? Or are you asking how to add the timestamp to your data structure? Or all of the above? Please [edit] your question and add more details, including a [mcve], so we can understand what you need and help you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the python [datetime-module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), especially the [`now()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now)-function.

```
import datetime

time_created = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ctime` from the `time` module like so:

```
def add(x, y):
    from time import ctime #import ctime
    var = x + y
    time_created = ctime() #get current time
    return var, time_created

print(add(1,2))
```

Output:

```
(3, 'Wed Mar  2 14:41:34 2022')
```

In this example we use `ctime` because it gives an easy to read `str` format.

We can apply this to your example like so:

```
def function_name(real_time_data):
    from time import ctime #import ctime
    ...
    return dict([data1,data2]), ctime()
```

Comment: Just a nitpick, but the parentheses in your return is redundant. In python `return x, y` implicitly returns it as a tuple

Comment: @Wondercricket true